# Looping to create multiple tables

Tags: r, loops

I would like to output 30 tables (each one based on a variable). The variables I want are stored in a list. For one I would use,

```
table(rad_survey_subset$Q32)
```

But I can't just say,

```
table(rad_survey_subset$list_of_variables)
```

Data looks like this

```
Q4  Q9  Q13
y   urban   
y   urban   99%
y   suburban    100%
y   rural   99%
y       98%
y   rural   98%
y   urban   97%
y   urban   >97%
y   suburban    100%
y   urban   
y   rural   98%
y   rural   98%
y   rural   100
y   urban   98.50%
y   rural   98%
y   Mixed/Other (please describe)   98%
y   rural   99%
y   urban   96%
y   urban   98.30%
y   urban   99%
y   urban   *2
```

Thanks you for any help. (Is it also possible to store these in a `data.frame`?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be `lapply( rad_survey_subset[1:30], table)`. Only if the number of unique elements were the same for every one of the 30 columns AND they all had the same levels would it make any sense to attempt to coerce them into a dataframe. Why not post a small example with say 3 or 4 columns?

Answer (score 0):

if the rad_survey_subset is a list you can use:

```
t_rad<-lapply(rad_survey_subset, table)
```

after that, if the return of this code are similar (i mean if it is matrix same nrow or same ncol)

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind,t_rad))
```

can give you what you want.

Comment: `questions_of_interest` is the name of the list.  `rad_survey_subset` is the name of the data.frame. I tried running your code `(t_rad<-lapply(questions_of_interest, table)` and it just gave me the output of the first item in the list.

Comment: i can just assume how is your variables. `questions_of_interest<-lapply(1:100, function(x)rnorm(100))` 

`t_rad<-lapply(questions_of_interest,table)`

`t_rad_df<-data.frame(do.call(rbind,t_rad))`